# How to rewrite strings sharing a similar pattern in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a list of dates that are written in the format:

```
20130103   
20130104
20130105  
20130106
20130107
```

And I want to rewrite them like this:

```
01/02/2013
01/03/2013
01/04/2013
01/05/2013
01/06/2013
01/07/2013
```

Is there any way to do this in Java?

The dates are stored in a text file, so I used a scanner to read them in one by one and store them into a string array, but I'm stuck as to what do next.

Comment: Read 4 characters, got the year. Read 2 more characters, got the month. Read 2 more characters, got the day. Reorder and join with delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String convertDate(String origDate)
{
    if (origDate.length == 8)
    {
        String year = origDate.substring(0, 4);
        String month = origDate.substring(4, 6);
        String day = origDate.substring(6, 8);
        return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Invalid Date Format";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use a *regular expression* with [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to group the first four digits, then the next two digits and then the final two digits. And rewrite the groups into your desired format. Something like,

```
String[] dates = { "20130102", "20130103", "20130104", //
        "20130105", "20130106", "20130107" };
for (String date : dates) {
    System.out.println(date.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "$2/$3/$1"));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
01/02/2013
01/03/2013
01/04/2013
01/05/2013
01/06/2013
01/07/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "20160428";
//int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(str); //this is to read the string into int
String 4char = str.substring(0,4);   //read int based of array type (starting position which is 0 and read up to position 3)
String 2char = str.substring(4,6)
String last2char = str.substring(6,7)
```

// int intDateSlash = Integer.parseInt(4char)
This is to read as number but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: please explain more detail of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the `java.time` api would have the advantage of validating the dates as valid dates, if you ever needed that.  Here is an example:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

public static String convert(String date){
    return LocalDate.parse(date, PARSER).format(FORMATTER);
}
```